# Can a question regarding driver validation on Windows 10 version 1607 be posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to repost [a Windows driver question from Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1113674/how-to-allow-cross-signed-kernel-drivers-in-windows-10-v1607-with-secure-boot-en) on Stack Overflow because:

- The research is valuable information for Stack Overflow users who develop Windows kernel drivers
- I hope to get hints which debugging techniques I could use to identify that secret registry key

However, this is clearly not a programming question, but on the other hand I probably won't get any valuable input from Super User. Any hints where I could/should place this question?

Background: Windows 10 Version 1607 (aka Anniversary Update) is now enforcing the tightened kernel driver certification which was already announced 2015 as a requirement for Windows 10. The new rule is that all Windows 10 drivers must be digitally signed by Microsoft, no more cross signing! Kernel driver developers must now use an Extended Validation (EV) code signing certificate and submit their drivers to the Windows Hardware Developer Center Dashboard Portal where the drivers will be signed by Microsoft after passing certain tests.

I've thoroughly researched the topic and summarized and verified the facts presented by Microsoft in their [Channel 9 - Plugfest28 - Driver-Certification-on-Windows-Client-and-Server video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Filter-Plugfest28/Driver-Certification-on-Windows-Client-and-Server) in a [Stack Exchange/Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113674/how-to-allow-cross-signed-kernel-drivers-in-windows-10-v1607-with-secure-boot-en) hoping to get answers regarding that mysterious secret registry key which supposedly allows cross-signed drivers on cleanly installed Windows 10 version 1607 systems with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Not every question that is a _real question_ does actually fit for being a question at Stack Oveflow, sorry.

Comment: You either ask someone to break the NDA, which can have legal consequences or you want to reverse engineer the system which might be  restricted in the Windows EULA. Your question is either asking for an off-site resource or a bit too broad. The last bit could be overcome if you share some attempt in your debugging. I'm not sure if your question is particular useful so don't be sad if your question is sprinkled with down votes ...

Comment: Hints for debugging techniques do not make good answers. But what is the registry key to allow cross-signed drivers to install on Win 10.1607 systems is a perfectly acceptable question for Stack Overflow. Driver development and code signing is a programming topic, so reasonable questions about it would be on-topic here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/windows-10/topics

Comment: @rene I hope you don't believe that performing a registry diff between an upgraded Windows 10 1607 and a freshly installed v1607 is actually reverse engineering?

Comment: @gollum No, don't worry, I'm sane..

Answer (score -4):

> However, this is clearly not a programming question but on the other hand I probably won't get any valuable input from superuser.

The one thing to do in such cases is to offer a bounty on Super User for the question there.

I see that you don't have enough reputation to offer one in Super User, so you may either participate more in that site or find a good samaritan to do it for you.

Bringing the case to the Meta of Super User may help, but that's not guaranteed.

But what you really need will not be found in any SE sites. You guys have to work with Microsoft to get your drivers signed. Even if you did get an answer here or on SU, what's keeping Microsoft from updating Windows 10 at any time to use a different key, or even disabling the feature you seek?

Comment: Offering a bounty doesn't make an off-topic question suddenly on topic. The only purpose of a bounty would be to encourage people to spend time investigating the problem (which might certainly be appropriate in this case, but your answer seems to imply something different).

Comment: @CodyGray sorry, I meant a bounty on SU, not on SO.